# Building (deprecated) Asset Map

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, react-native

I'm trying to build a react-native project using the Packager, but I always get a  **Building (deprecated) Asset Map** message. Anybody knows how to avoid the deprecated build? Thanks!

Here are the Packager logs:

```
[5:12:29 PM] <START> Building Dependency Graph
[5:12:29 PM] <START> Crawling File System
[5:12:29 PM] <START> Loading bundles layout
[5:12:29 PM] <END>   Loading bundles layout (1ms)

React packager ready.

[5:12:37 PM] <END>   Crawling File System (8041ms)
[5:12:37 PM] <START> Building in-memory fs for JavaScript
[5:12:38 PM] <END>   Building in-memory fs for JavaScript (990ms)
[5:12:38 PM] <START> Building in-memory fs for Assets
[5:12:39 PM] <END>   Building in-memory fs for Assets (1023ms)
[5:12:39 PM] <START> Building Haste Map
[5:12:39 PM] <START> Building (deprecated) Asset Map
[5:12:39 PM] <END>   Building (deprecated) Asset Map (153ms)
[5:12:40 PM] <END>   Building Haste Map (746ms)
[5:12:40 PM] <END>   Building Dependency Graph (10804ms)
```